# Ideal way to get association of ActiveRecord::Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

Consider the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end
```

Now I want to get posts for some banned users.

```
User.where(is_banned: true).posts
```

This produces a `NoMethodError` as posts is not defined on `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

What is the slickest way of making the code above work?

I can think of

```
User.where(is_banned: true).map(&:posts).flatten.uniq
```

But this is inefficient.

I can also think of

```
user_scope = User.where(is_banned: true)
Post.where(user: user_scope)
```

This requires the user association to be set up in the `Post` model and it appears to generate a nested select. I don't know about the efficiency.

Ideally, I would like a technique that allows traversing multiple relations, so I can write something like:

```
User.where(is_banned: true).posts.comments.votes.voters
```

which should give me every voter (user) who has voted for a comment on a post written by a banned user.

Comment: *"This requires the user association to be set up in the Post model"* Why is the user association not set up in the Post model? Its should be a User has_many :posts and a Post belongs_to :user. You could do `Post.joins(:user).where(users: {is_banned: true})` which will execute 1 query and return the results you want.

Comment: It is, I am just noting that it's mandatory which I find to be a drawback. Hence, I am wondering if a better solution exist.

Comment: What is the draw back of ORM referential integrity do you intend to have posts that belong to no one? Generally from a database integrity standpoint these would be true and enforced primary and foreign keys to makes sure everything stays sound from a referential stand point.

Comment: Good question, I have been taught to delay adding ActiveRecord relations until the point where I need them. The argument I was given was that an undefined relation cannot be access and hence it simplifies the interface of the ActiveRecord object with the benefits that simple classes gives. I won't judge the strength of this argument and I think it's outside the scope of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use `joins`?

```
Post.joins(:user).where(users: {is_banned: true})
```

This will generate SQL to the effect of

```
SELECT * 
FROM posts
INNER JOIN users ON posts.user_id = users.id
WHERE users.is_banned = true
```

This seems to be exactly what you are looking for. As far as your long chain goes you can do the same thing just with a much deeper join.

Comment: Also consider `merge` instead of `where`: `.merge(User.where(is_banned: true))`

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
User.where(is_banned: true)
```

will be and ActiveRecord::Relation and you need one record. So doing if from the User model would be more complicated. Depending on how the relationship is set up you could add a scope in your Post model.

`scope :banned_users, -> { joins(:users).where('is_banned = ?', true) }`

Then you would just call `Post.banned_users` to get all the post created by banned users.

Comment: I would change `where('is banned =? '` to `where(' users.is_banned =? '`. The multipart identifier will allow an is_banned attribute on a post without collisions but I agree the use of a scope is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start of a solution for your ideal technique. It probably doesn't work as written with extended chaining, and performance would probably be pretty bad. It would also require that you define the `inverse_of` for each association —

```
module LocalRelationExtensions

  def method_missing(meth, *args, &blk)
    if (assoc = self.klass.reflect_on_association(meth)) && (inverse = assoc.inverse_of)
      assoc.klass.joins(inverse.name).merge(self)
    else
      super
    end
  end

end

ActiveRecord::Relation.include(LocalRelationExtensions)
```

But really you should use the comment of @engineersmnky.